# column names per row top 3 dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe

Let us say we have the following data frame in R:

```
DF <- as.data.frame.matrix(matrix(sample(1:15,15),ncol=5,nrow=3))

   V1  V2 V3 V4 V5
1  15   8  3 14  4
2  11   2  5 13  6
3   9   7 10 12  1
```

I'm trying to retrieve the column name of the top three values per row. I would like to get a new data frame with the following information:

```
1 V1 V4 V2
2 V4 V1 V5
3 V4 V3 V1
```

I tried by using apply and dapply but it is not working. I designed a function to use in apply but it is not working as expected. Could you give me any hint to tackle this. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735859/for-each-row-return-the-column-name-of-the-largest-value) should be of help.

Comment: The correct tag for R questions is data.frame, not dataframes. Please don't use the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the rows  (`apply` with `MARGIN=1`), get the numeric index of the elements in the row decreasingly with `order`, use that to order the column names, get the first 3 elements with `head`, transpose the output and convert to `data.frame`.

```
 as.data.frame(t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) 
   head(names(DF)[order(-x)],3))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#  V1 V2 V3
#1 V1 V4 V2
#2 V4 V1 V5
#3 V4 V3 V1
```