# Getting column names for max value in each row

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset which looks like the following-

```
cluster1      cluster2      cluster3
0.0795604798  0.0934697636 -0.396044650
0.0086171605 -0.1467907623 -0.396044650
1.8838058726 -0.1507548515 -0.396044650
```

I want to get the cluster number for each row, which will be the maximum value. It should look something like this-

```
value           cluster
0.0934697636    cluster2
0.0086171605    cluster1
1.8838058726    cluster1
```

I'm doing it in R. If I use the following command, I get the maximum observation from each row-

```
k=colnames(apply(cscore,1,max))
```

But I'm not sure how to get the cluster name as well.

Comment: A closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17735859

Answer (score 4):

We can use `max.col` to get the column index of maximum value for each row, `cbind` it with the row index to extract the maximum 'value' in each row ('value'), and use the column index to get the corresponding column names ('cluster').

```
j1 <- max.col(df1, "first")
value <- df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), j1)]
cluster <- names(df1)[j1]
res <- data.frame(value, cluster)
res
#       value  cluster
#1 0.093469764 cluster2
#2 0.008617161 cluster1
#3 1.883805873 cluster1
```