# Extract column name using which function

Tags: r

I'm working on a R code. I have a dataset which has Product(variables) and under it I have its annual spendings for 10 years. Now I want to do a row - wise search and find the max annual spending and extract that max value's variable/field name.

Comment: I"m trying using "which"  function but not able to crack the code.

Comment: Try `which.max()`?

Comment: Can you add some sample data, some sample output and what you've tried so far?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735859/for-each-row-return-the-column-name-of-the-largest-value/17735894) can help.

Answer (score 0):

I would approch the problem as follows assuming each variable makes its own column in an R data.frame df.
first extract the max Value for each row

(Clarification: I am using the pip operator "%>%" from the package dplyr)

```
maxRow <- sapply(t(df) %>% as_data_frame(),max)
```

then collect the column name containing the max value for each row

```
sapply(1:nrow(df),function(idx){names(df)[df[idx,] == maxV[idx]]})
```

alternatively usig thecatalyst suggestion just do:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df),function(idx){which.max(df[idx,]) %>% names()})
```