# Convert from Wide to Long format for mutually exclusive categories

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` similar to:

```
> df<-data.frame(ID=1:5, Age30_40=c(1,0,0,1,0),Age40_50=c(0,1,1,0,0), Age50_60=c(0,0,0,0,1))
> df
  ID Age30_40 Age40_50 Age50_60
1  1        1        0        0
2  2        0        1        0
3  3        0        1        0
4  4        1        0        0
5  5        0        0        1
```

I want to convert this wide data to a long data such that my output is as follows:

```
ID  AgeRange
1   Age30_40
2   Age40_50
3   Age40_50
4   Age30_40
5   Age50_60
```

However, all that I could manage thus far is this:

```
> library(tidyr)
> gather(df, AgeRange, InThisRange, Age30_40:Age50_60)
   ID AgeRange InThisRange
1   1 Age30_40   1
2   2 Age30_40   0
3   3 Age30_40   0
4   4 Age30_40   1
5   5 Age30_40   0
6   1 Age40_50   0
7   2 Age40_50   1
8   3 Age40_50   1
9   4 Age40_50   0
10  5 Age40_50   0
11  1 Age50_60   0
12  2 Age50_60   0
13  3 Age50_60   0
14  4 Age50_60   0
15  5 Age50_60   1
```

Since this is a simplified example, I can loop through each entry and keep the only non-zero `AgeRange` entry corresponding to each ID by checking the boolean variable `InThisRange`. However, this is definitely not a very efficient solution for large data frames. Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: Related: [For each row return the column name of the largest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735859/for-each-row-return-the-column-name-of-the-largest-value)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `max.col` from `base R` (assuming that there is only a single 1 per row)

```
cbind(df[1], AgeRange = names(df)[-1][max.col(df[-1])])
#  ID AgeRange
#1  1 Age30_40
#2  2 Age40_50
#3  3 Age40_50
#4  4 Age30_40
#5  5 Age50_60
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Just a couple of things. 1. My actual dataframe has many other columns. This operation is deleting all other columns. 2. The number of rows are higher after the operation compared to the number of rows before. I think this is due to the two errors cbind is throwing regarding non-identical attributes and introducing NAs by coercion. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DotPi  You can subset those columns you need and `cbind` with the 'AgeRange'  The second part is not clear as the `max.col` will output one value for each row

Answer (score 0):

An `apply` based solution can be achieved using `dynamic` names of column.

```
#Columns to select to change in long format
cols <- grepl("^Age.*",names(df))

cbind(df[!cols], AgeRange = apply(df[cols],1,function(x)names(x[x!=0][1])))
#   ID AgeRange
# 1  1 Age30_40
# 2  2 Age40_50
# 3  3 Age40_50
# 4  4 Age30_40
# 5  5 Age50_60
```

**Note:** The above solution will consider only `left-most` column where multiple columns got `1` in same row.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```r
library(dplyr)

#add column names which you don't want to convert to long data
ignore_cols <- c("ID", "another_col")

df %>%
  select(-one_of(ignore_cols)) %>%
  mutate(AgeRange = names(.)[max.col(.)]) %>%
  select(AgeRange) %>%
  bind_cols(df[,ignore_cols])
```

**Output is:**

```
  AgeRange ID another_col
1 Age30_40  1         101
2 Age40_50  2         102
3 Age40_50  3         103
4 Age30_40  4         104
5 Age50_60  5         105
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Age30_40 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0), Age40_50 = c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 0), Age50_60 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1), another_col = 101:105), .Names = c("ID", 
"Age30_40", "Age40_50", "Age50_60", "another_col"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Note: For the illustration purpose I have added one more column (i.e. `another_col`).