# Avoid NA while calculating Max Row Using R data table

Tags: r, data.table

I need to get column names of rows where row has maximum value and [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923381/4575581/)  perfectly suits my situation. Only thing is that My data.table has NA in it and I have been trying to get it worked by ignoring NA

**Data**

```
 set.seed(45)
    DT <- data.table(matrix(sample(10, 10^7, TRUE), ncol=10))
    DT[, MAX := colnames(.SD)[max.col(.SD, ties.method="first")]]
  DT$VX <- NA
```

Code that works without NA in data

```
DT[, MAX := colnames(.SD)[max.col(.SD, ties.method="first")]]
```

below is what I tried with N.A. in data

```
> DT[, MAX := colnames(.SD)[max.col(replace(.SD, is.na(DT), -Inf), ties.method="first")]]
Warning message:
In max.col(replace(.SD, is.na(DT), -Inf), ties.method = "first") :
  NAs introduced by coercion

> DT[, MAX := colnames(.SD)[max.col(.SD,na.rm=TRUE, ties.method="first")]]
Error in max.col(.SD, na.rm = TRUE, ties.method = "first") : 
  unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  Did you meant `is.na(.SD)`

Comment: @OmerFarooq The link to `This answer` is not working. Please correct it.

Comment: Provide an example where this problem actually appears. `set.seed(45); m = matrix(sample(c(1,NA), 4, replace=TRUE), 2, 2); max.col(replace(m, is.na(m), -Inf), ties.method="first")` works fine, right?

Comment: You already created a `MAX` column which is `character` string and that could be the reason for `NA` when you do a second time without removing the `MAX` column

Comment: This works but its outputs column index rather than column index.

Comment: Once i remove the `MAX` column (`DT[, MAX := NULL]`)
 it is working as intended `DT[, names(.SD)[max.col(replace(.SD, is.na(.SD), -Inf), 'first')]]#
 [1] "V1"  "V2"  "V8"  "V8"  "V3"  "V8"  "V2"  "V7"  "V10" "V10"` (took a smaller sample)\

Comment: Yeah this works fine if MAX is removed. It's  strange to me.