# Collapse matrix to vector and replace values with column names

Tags: r, matrix

There is a matrix like this:

```
m <- matrix(c(F,T,F,T,F,T,F,T,F, F,F,T,F,T,F,T,F,T), nrow=9, ncol=2,
           dimnames=list(c(), c('1x2x24','2x2x24')))

    1x2x24 2x2x24
[1,]  FALSE  FALSE
[2,]   TRUE  FALSE
[3,]  FALSE   TRUE
[4,]   TRUE  FALSE
[5,]  FALSE   TRUE
[6,]   TRUE  FALSE
[7,]  FALSE   TRUE
[8,]   TRUE  FALSE
[9,]  FALSE   TRUE
```

Presumably there is only a single TRUE per row. What would be the best way to get a vector like this:

```
NA, 1x2x24, 2x2x24, 1x2x24, 2x2x24, 1x2x24, 2x2x24, 1x2x24, 2x2x24
```

One way to get it is to replace each TRUE in each column with column name and each FALSE with NA or "". Then merge all columns across rows with paste(). I'm not quite sure how to do this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: [For each row return the column name of the largest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735859/for-each-row-return-the-column-name-of-the-largest-value). Use `rowSums` to find rows with two `FALSE`.

Comment: Does it need to be NA-aware? `rowSums(m, na.rm=T)` works.

Comment: *"Presumably there is only a single TRUE per row."* Are you trying to reverse one-hotting a categorical or int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the input matrix `m` defined reproducibly in the Note at the end if we matrix multiply it by 1:2 which is the same as multiplying each row by 1:2 which gives a vector with the same length as the number of rows such that each element is 0 if there are no TRUE values in that row, 1 if there is a TRUE value in the first column of that row and 2 if there is a TRUE value in the second column of that row.  Add 1 to that and index into a 3-tuple whose first element is NA and subsequent elements are the column names.

```
c(NA, colnames(m))[m %*% 1:2 + 1]
## [1] NA       "1x2x24" "2x2x24" "1x2x24" "2x2x24" "1x2x24" "2x2x24" "1x2x24"
## [9] "2x2x24"
```

Alternately we can use the same computation but use it to define a factor which we convert to a character string:

```
as.character(factor(m %*% 1:2 + 1, lab = c(NA, colnames(m))))
```

If it turns out that it is possible to have two TRUE values in a row then for such rows the computation gives 4 so just replace `c(NA, colnames(m))` with `c(NA, colnames(m), "both")`, say.

### Note

```
m <- structure(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE
), .Dim = c(9L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("[1,]", "[2,]", "[3,]", 
"[4,]", "[5,]", "[6,]", "[7,]", "[8,]", "[9,]"), c("1x2x24", 
"2x2x24")))
```

Comment: This is very nice but some variables are hard-coded.

Comment: Use `ncol(m)` instead of 2 if your input matrix does not have 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

I used the function `coalesce` from the package `dplyr` once all the `FALSE` values were turned into `NA`s with an `ifelse` function. This isn't the cleanest way to do it, but it works. For completeness: If `dplyr` is not yet installed you will need to run `install.packages("dplyr")` first.

```
library(dplyr)

X <- matrix(c(F,T,F,T,F,T,F,T,F, F,F,T,F,T,F,T,F,T), nrow=9, ncol=2,
            dimnames=list(c(), c('1x2x24','2x2x24')))
> X
      1x2x24 2x2x24
 [1,]  FALSE  FALSE
 [2,]   TRUE  FALSE
 [3,]  FALSE   TRUE
 [4,]   TRUE  FALSE
 [5,]  FALSE   TRUE
 [6,]   TRUE  FALSE
 [7,]  FALSE   TRUE
 [8,]   TRUE  FALSE
 [9,]  FALSE   TRUE

# Here we can use ifelse to turn F into NA
#> ifelse(X[,1]==F, NA_integer_, colnames(X)[1])
#[1] NA       "1x2x24" NA       "1x2x24" NA       "1x2x24" NA       "1x2x24" NA      

#> ifelse(X[,2]==F, NA_integer_, colnames(X)[2])
#[1] NA       NA       "2x2x24" NA       "2x2x24" NA       "2x2x24" NA       "2x2x24"


y<-as.character(data.frame(ifelse(X[,1]==F, NA_integer_, colnames(X)[1]))[,1])
z<-as.character(data.frame(ifelse(X[,2]==F, NA_integer_, colnames(X)[2]))[,1])

coalesce(y,z)
[1] NA       "1x2x24" "2x2x24" "1x2x24" "2x2x24" "1x2x24" "2x2x24" "1x2x24" "2x2x24"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
C1<-c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,
   TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE, 
   TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,
   TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE, 
   TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)
print(C1)
m<-matrix(C1,ncol=2)
colnames(m)<-c("1x2x24","2x2x24")
vector_result<-(apply(m, 1, 
function(u) paste(names(which(u)), collapse="NA" ) 
))
idx<-(which(vector_result=="")) # replace "" with NA     
vector_result[idx]="NA"
print(vector_result)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
apply(m,1,function(x) names(which(x))[1])
# [1,]     [2,]     [3,]     [4,]     [5,]     [6,]     [7,]     [8,]     [9,]  
#   NA "1x2x24" "2x2x24" "1x2x24" "2x2x24" "1x2x24" "2x2x24" "1x2x24" "2x2x24"
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, if you could parametarize your answer, such as to remove hard-coded variables (i.e. 1:2 + 1) then I think it would be comparable to this one.