# dplyr: Need help returning column index of first non-NA value in every row

Tags: r, dplyr

I've recently started trying to do all of my code in the tidyverse. This has sometimes lead me to difficulties. Here is a simple task that I haven't been able to complete in the tidyverse: I need a column in a dataframe that returns the position index of the first non-na value from the left. Does anyone know how to achieve this in dplyr using mutate?

Here is the desired output.

```r
data.frame(                           
"X1"=c(100,rep(NA,8)),
"X2"=c(NA,10,rep(NA,7)),
"X3"=c(NA,NA,1000,1000,rep(NA,5)),
"X4"=c(rep(NA,4),25,50,10,40,50),
"FirstNonNaPosition"=c(1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
)
```

Comment: Related canonical: [For each row return the column name of the largest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735859/for-each-row-return-the-column-name-of-the-largest-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `apply` as well:

```
data.frame(                           
"X1"=c(100,rep(NA,8)),
"X2"=c(NA,10,rep(NA,7)),
"X3"=c(NA,NA,1000,1000,rep(NA,5)),
"X4"=c(rep(NA,4),25,50,10,40,50),
"FirstNonNaPosition"=c(1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
) %>%
  mutate(First_Non_NA_Pos = apply(., 1, function(x) which(!is.na(x))[1]))

   X1 X2   X3 X4 FirstNonNaPosition First_Non_NA_Pos
1 100 NA   NA NA                  1                1
2  NA 10   NA NA                  2                2
3  NA NA 1000 NA                  3                3
4  NA NA 1000 NA                  3                3
5  NA NA   NA 25                  4                4
6  NA NA   NA 50                  4                4
7  NA NA   NA 10                  4                4
8  NA NA   NA 40                  4                4
9  NA NA   NA 50                  4                4
```

Answer (score 4):

An easier and efficient `base R` option would be `max.col` after replacing the `NA` elements to 0

```
max.col(replace(df2[1:4], is.na(df2[1:4]), 0), 'first')
```

Or even

```
df2$FirstNonNaPosition <- max.col(!is.na(df2[1:4]), "first")
df2$FirstNonNaPosition
#[1] 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

---

With `tidyverse`, a possible option is `pmap`

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(FirstNonNaPosition = pmap_int(.[-5], ~ 
                          which.max(!is.na(c(...)))))
```

Or wrap the `max.col`

```
df2 %>% 
   mutate(FirstNonNaPosition = max.col(!is.na(.[-5]), 'first'))
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(X1 = c(100, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X2 = c(NA, 
10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X3 = c(NA, NA, 1000, 1000, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), X4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 25, 50, 10, 40, 50), 
    FirstNonNaPosition = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Right. I can get this done out of dplyr, but I need to incorporate it into a pipe. How would I incorporate this into a dplyr command?

Comment: @mcmahon.an  I would use `pmap` i.e. `df2 %>% mutate(FirstNonNaPosition = pmap(.[-5], ~ which.max(!is.na(c(..))))`

Comment: @mcmahon.an Anything you can do outside of a "pipeline" to generate a vector you can also just put inside `mutate`. Here you can copy the code directly to do `df2 %>% 
  mutate(newcol = max.col(!is.na(df2[1:4]), "first"))`. Optionally, replace `df2` with `.`.

Answer (score 4):

Also a `base R` possibility:

```
apply(df, 1, which.max)

[1] 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

The same with `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(FirstNonNaPosition = apply(., 1, which.max))
```

A modification for a scenario mentioned by @Andrew:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) which.max(!is.na(x)))
```

The same with `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(FirstNonNaPosition = apply(., 1, function(x) which.max(!is.na(x))))
```

Comment: There is a possibility `which.max` will fail if there are several non-NA values in a row. E.g., if row 5, column X3 is 10.

Comment: Right. So I'd just need to have it grab the first one.

Comment: @Andrew I considered a structure as in the example, however, I included a possibility for a scenario you mentioned. Thank you for noticing it :)