# In R: row wise return max value and corresponding column name

Tags: r, dataframe, substring, rowwise

I am trying to obtain the max value row wise across several columns, and create 2 new columns with the max value, and the corresponding column name.
Then, using the column name, I need to select the value of another column that shares a substring of that column name.

This is an example of what I trying to solve:

```
measure_day1 <-  c(1,2,5)
measure_day2 <- c(5,7,1)
measure_day3 <- c(2,3,9)
temp_day1 <- c(25, 27, 29)
temp_day2 <- c(31, 33, 35)
temp_day3 <- c(14, 16, 19)

df <- data.frame(measure_day1, measure_day2, measure_day3, temp_day1, temp_day2, temp_day3)

  measure_day1 measure_day2 measure_day3 temp_day1 temp_day2 temp_day3
1            1            5            2        25        31        14
2            2            7            3        27        33        16
3            5            1            9        29        35        19
```

And this would be the result:

```
 measure_day1 measure_day2 measure_day3 temp_day1 temp_day2 temp_day3 measure_max day_measure_max temp_day_measure_max
1            1            5            2        25        31        14           5    measure_day2                   31
2            2            7            3        27        33        16           7    measure_day2                   33
3            5            1            9        29        35        19           9    measure_day3                   19
```

I found this similar question but could not complete my task.

[For each row return the column name of the largest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735859/for-each-row-return-the-column-name-of-the-largest-value)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `tidyverse` approach. It can be more practical reshaping data to long previously creating an id per row and then extract the desired values using `filter`. Using `pivot_wider()` you can have the desired values and then the filter for max values is applied. Finally you can merge to your original data using `left_join()` and the id you created based on rows. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  left_join(df %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  separate(name,c('Var','Day'),sep='_') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=Var,values_from=value) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(measure==max(measure)) %>%
  mutate(Day=paste0('measure_',Day)) %>% select(-measure) %>%
  rename(measure_max=Day,temp_day_measure_max=temp)) %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
  measure_day1 measure_day2 measure_day3 temp_day1 temp_day2 temp_day3  measure_max temp_day_measure_max
1            1            5            2        25        31        14 measure_day2                   31
2            2            7            3        27        33        16 measure_day2                   33
3            5            1            9        29        35        19 measure_day3                   19
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R method :

```
#Select measure columns
measure_cols <- grep('measure', names(df), value = TRUE)
#Select temp_day column
temp_cols <- grep('temp_day', names(df))
#Get the index of max value in measure column
inds <- max.col(df[measure_cols])
#Get max value in measure columns
df$measure_max <- do.call(pmax, df[measure_cols])
#Get the name of max value in measure columns
df$day_measure_max <- measure_cols[inds]
#Get the corresponding temp column. 
df$temp_day_measure_max <- df[temp_cols][cbind(1:nrow(df), inds)]
df

#  measure_day1 measure_day2 measure_day3 temp_day1 temp_day2 temp_day3
#1            1            5            2        25        31        14
#2            2            7            3        27        33        16
#3            5            1            9        29        35        19

#  measure_max day_measure_max temp_day_measure_max
#1           5    measure_day2                   31
#2           7    measure_day2                   33
#3           9    measure_day3                   19
```