# Determine the column with maximum value for each data frame row, accounting for ties

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` with several columns, where the values are integers. For example:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(s1 = as.integer(runif(10,0,10)),
                 s2 = as.integer(runif(10,0,10)),
                 s3 = as.integer(runif(10,0,10)))
```

My question is how to efficiently add a column to this `data.frame` that will label the column that has the maximum value for each row, but if there are ties the label will be `NA`.

The slow way of doing this:

```
df$max <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(r){
  max.idx <- which(df[r,] == max(df[r,]))
  if(length(max.idx) == 1){
    max.label <- colnames(df)[max.idx]
  } else{
    max.label <- NA
  }
  max.label
})

> df
   s1 s2 s3  max
1   2  2  9   s3
2   3  1  2   s1
3   5  6  6 <NA>
4   9  3  1   s1
5   2  7  2   s2
6   8  4  3   s1
7   9  7  0   s1
8   6  9  3   s2
9   6  3  8   s3
10  0  7  3   s2
```

I'm looking for something faster for a much larger `data.frame`

Comment: googling your verbatim question, top result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735859/for-each-row-return-the-column-name-of-the-largest-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to get the index of the column with max value in each row.  Then, to change those with `ties` for max to NA, an option is to do a comparision with the max value in each row with that of the dataset, convert to logical vector with `rowSums` and replace those elements in `mx` with ties to `NA`

```
mx <- names(df)[max.col(df, "first")]
df$max <- replace(mx, rowSums(do.call(pmax, df) == df) > 1, NA)
```

-output

```
df
#   s1 s2 s3  max
#1   2  2  9   s3
#2   3  1  2   s1
#3   5  6  6 <NA>
#4   9  3  1   s1
#5   2  7  2   s2
#6   8  4  3   s1
#7   9  7  0   s1
#8   6  9  3   s2
#9   6  3  8   s3
#10  0  7  3   s2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @akrun. But I see that `max.col` doesn't have an option to return `NA` in case of ties (its documentation says: `ties.method = c("random", "first", "last")`). Any alternative?