# apply max function to multiple rows

Tags: r, max, apply

I have a dataframe `df` like this:
[image]

I want to add a new column which shows the name of the max value among 5 variables. For example, for the first row: the max value is 5, the name of max value is `Olfactory`. Similarly repeat for other rows. The expected dataframe should be:
[image]

My code is:

```
find_max<-apply(across(.cols=c(12:16),MARGIN=1), FUN=max)
Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
```

Is there idea to fix this error? thank you in advance!

Comment: `apply` doesn't have `across`.  You need `apply(df[12:16], 1, FUN = max)` or can use `do.call(pmax, df[12:16])`

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735859/for-each-row-return-the-column-name-of-the-largest-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   df$Main_Mode <- names(df)[12:16][max.col(df[12:16])]
```