# Make new column based on column title and value R

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a data frame like below:

`df <- data.frame(x1=c(1,0,0,0),x2=c(0,1,0,0),x3=c(0,0,0,1),x4=c(0,0,1,0))`

How can I make a new column with the title name based on if the certain row is equal to 1? So the new data frame would look like:

`df2 <- data.frame(x1=c(1,0,0,0),x2=c(0,1,0,0),x3=c(0,0,0,1),x4=c(0,0,1,0),name=c(x1,x2,x4,x3))`

Comment: [Any of these methods should work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17735859/903061). You can also search for "convert dummy variables to factor" for plenty of similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max.col`:

```r
df$name <- colnames(df)[max.col(df == 1)]
```

```r
  x1 x2 x3 x4 name
1  1  0  0  0   x1
2  0  1  0  0   x2
3  0  0  0  1   x4
4  0  0  1  0   x3
```